# UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

tableView layout override when I set inside layout subview

```
CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    dictNoti = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    cell.pageIndex = indexPath.row;
    cell.checkGoButton = YES;
    cell.tblViewCltn = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [cell.tblDetailView layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell.tblDetailView setNeedsLayout];
    cell.dataArr = collectionData;
```

Comment: why do you need a tableview inside a collectionviewCell?

Comment: Where is your problem exactly?

Comment: anyway you need to call reloadData on your tableview here. not layoutifneed or setneedslayout